# Near field probing technique

Tags: voltage, current, electromagnetism, emc

I am reading about the near field probing using Electric field probes and Magnetic field probes.

I understand that E field probes would pickup voltage changes and the H field probes would pick up current changes. But I am not able to find when to use which probe?

Can someone tell me when to use which probe for EMI debugging? Like, If I am looking for emissions in my circuit board, for which purpose should I use which probe and when to use them?

Comment: You would use both probes. And a far-field antenna for propagating power. And a clamp probe for signals propagating on your cables. And whatever other antennae the EMI testing requirement specified, assuming you're testing it to meet some regulation.

Comment: Could you tell where to use which probe?

Comment: All probes in all places. However, if you're tracing a fault current for instance, then a magnetic probe will be better than an electric one. Part of the problem of EMI debugging is that even though you've designed the thing to the best of your intuition, in any non-trivial circuit it's not obvious what is going to leak from where. So you have to test for everything.

Answer (score 1):

This is a difficult question to answer because there isn't a clear one.

You use the probe that detects the field you are currently concerned about. Alternatively, if you have no clue where to look, you are better off going over it with both probes in turn to try and identify locations of high field strength. Note that there can be a significant H-field at some distance from the current itself and around things like antennas.

But be warned; EMI troubleshooting is a black art. EMI does not obey the circuit and enclosure designers' intent, it obeys the laws of physics that schoolkids learn, and can indicate all kinds of phenomena. For example a strong local field across a gap in the shielding probably means that one half is loose and acting as an antenna, even though there is nothing detectable against the shielding itself. But what is coupling to the shielding and why? Remove the piece to get at the circuit, and the interference vanishes. Turkey foil, ferrite clamps and low cunning are often more important than the choice of probe.

Comment: Is "turkey foil" a term for a specialized material used for this kind of work, or just a term for aluminum foil similar to the one used to cook turkeys?

Comment: Just common aluminium foil. It's great for on-the-fly shielding to see if it makes any difference. Can be taped to an enclosure or ground plane, just never let it near live wiring without suitable precautions! The basic method for a box of tricks is: festoon the darn thing in foil and ferrites until it stops hooting, then remove the stuff bit by bit until it starts again. Individual circuit boards need a little more finesse.

Comment: Thanks! I think your description of the way the foil is used might be useful to edit into your post as it adds value (comments tend to disappear occasionally as they're meant to be ephemeral)

Comment: The foil bit is not really in answer to this question. Maybe I should write a book. :)